# Error in case select statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the code below that is throwing an error "remaining text does not appear to be part of a formula" and highlights from the Default: statement down.  I cannot locate the error

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar SoftCreditCountCY_Alum;
shared numbervar SoftCreditCountCY_NonAlum;
shared currencyvar SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum;
shared currencyvar SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum;
shared currencyvar Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum;
shared currencyvar Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum;

if {CnSmryGft_1.CnSmryGft_1_Total_Gift_amount} > 0 and {CnAttrCat_1.CnAttrCat_1_Description} = 0 and {CnAttrCat_2.CnAttrCat_2_Description} = 0 and {CnAttrCat_3.CnAttrCat_3_Description} = 0 and {CnAttrCat_4.CnAttrCat_4_Description} > 0 
    and {CnBio_All.CnBio_Constit_Code} = "Alumni" then

    Select {CnBio.CnBio_Constit_Code}
        Case 'Alumni':
            SoftCreditCountCY_Alum := SoftCreditCountCY_Alum + 1;
            SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum :=SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
            Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum :=Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};            
        Default:
            SoftCreditCountCY_NonAlum := SoftCreditCountCY_NonAlum + 1;
            SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum :=SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
            Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum :=Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Case statement included multiple executions/calcs, the executions/calcs must be encased in parenthesis

```
  Select {CnBio.CnBio_Constit_Code}
    Case "Alumni":
    **(**
        SoftCreditCountCY_Alum := SoftCreditCountCY_Alum + 1;
        SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum :=SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
        Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum :=Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_Alum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};            
    **)**
    Default:
    **(**
        SoftCreditCountCY_NonAlum := SoftCreditCountCY_NonAlum + 1;
        SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum :=SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
        Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum :=Total_SoftCredit_CY_TotalDollars_NonAlum + {CnGf_1SfCrdt_1.CnGf_1SfCrdt_1_Amount};
    **)**
```